# Десериализация map в objectMapper

Tags: java

У меня есть сервер, который возращает `HashMap<ProductEntity, Integer>`
при попытке извлечь map путем

```
TypeReference<HashMap<ProductEntity, Integer>> tr = new TypeReference<HashMap<ProductEntity, Integer>>() {};

productsCartMap = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, tr);
```

получаю исключение

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class ua.itea.model.ProductEntity].

Я извлекал стоку из inputStream. Сервер  корректно возвращает json мапы.
В интернете я нашел решение, что нужно в приватном поле класса объявить map с аннотацией, что я и сделал.

```
@JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = MyPairDeserializer.class)
private HashMap<ProductEntity, Integer> productsCartMap;
```

Также объявил класс `MyPairDeserializer`.

```
public class MyPairDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {

    @Override
    public Object deserializeKey(String s, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        return null;//описать, как десериализовать ключ map объект ProductEntity, из входной строки:
    }
}
```

Но дальше не пойму,что в теле метода писать? А может есть и другие способы попроще?

Comment: А как должен выглядеть JSON _после_ сериализации мапы с ключом `ProductEntity`?  Более простой вариант -- использовать id экземпляра `ProductEntity` в качестве ключа.

Comment: Я так и сделал, подогнал под id. Хотя это не то что  я хотел изначально